# What's the difference between a "normal" Google+ page and a "My Business" one?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I just tried to correct our company's address on Google Maps and ended up creating a "My Business" Google+ page in the process.

We already had a Google+ profile, but this "My Business" page is also marked as a "verified local business".

We would prefer to only maintain a single profile and I'm not really sure why Google would want me to create multiple pages. So, what is the difference between the two kinds of pages and how would I best go about merging the two now?